# How to use regex to append characters before carriage return and newline

Tags: regex, python-3.x

```
var = 'line1samplehere\r\nline2samplehere\r\nline3samplehere\r\n'
add = '12345'
```

I want to be able to search where '\r\n' is located and append the add string before that. I've researched and tried re.sub replacement`re.sub(r'("\r\n"), add,var)` but obviously having errors. Any advice?

Comment: What errors? Balance your quotes and use `add + '\r\n`

Comment: Don't put the double quotes around the part you're trying to capture, unless you want to capture those quotes. Change `r'("\r\n")` to `r'(\r\n)'`.

Comment: `var.replace('\r\n', add + '\r\n')`, no need for any regex.